# SQL LISTAGG Min and Max Function Issue

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, minmax, listagg

Need to find min and max date inside of list tag 
Like this in one column Min Date:01/01/2015  / Max Date:01/05/2015

```
SELECT D.ITEM_ID AS "ItemId",
       C.NAME AS "ItemName",
       D.UOM_ID AS "UomId",
       B.DESCRIPTION AS "Uom",
       sum(D.REQUIRED_QTY) AS "Quantity",
       LISTAGG(A.REASON, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY A.REASON) "ReasonType",
       LISTAGG(D.REQUIRED_DATE, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY D.REQUIRED_DATE) "PoRequiredDate",  
       LISTAGG(D.PO_COMMENT, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY D.PO_COMMENT) "Comment"
FROM BIZZXE_V2_SCH.REASONS A,
     BIZZXE_V2_SCH.UOMS B,
     BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEMS C,
     BIZZXE_V2_SCH.PO_REQUEST_ITEMS D,
     BIZZXE_V2_SCH.PO_REQUESTS E
WHERE E.PO_REQUEST_ID=D.PO_REQUEST_ID
  AND D.ITEM_ID=C.ITEM_ID
  AND D.UOM_ID=B.UOM_ID
  AND D.REASON_ID=A.REASON_ID
GROUP BY D.ITEM_ID, C.NAME, D.UOM_ID, B.DESCRIPTION
```

Need  to add Min dt and Max dt to one column as a "PoRequiredDate"

```
 WITH DATA AS(
   SELECT  listagg(REQUIRED_DATE, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY REQUIRED_DATE) dt
    FROM PO_REQUEST_ITEMS 
  WHERE PO_REQUEST_ID =16

  )
 SELECT dt,
        SUBSTR(dt, 1, instr(dt, ',', 1, 1)-1) min_dt,
         SUBSTR(dt, instr(dt, ',', -1, 1)+1)   max_dt
  FROM data
  /
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use syntax "KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST/LAST...)" for your purpose:

```
   'Min Date: '||min(REQUIRED_DATE) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY REQUIRED_DATE) ||
' / Max Date: '||min(REQUIRED_DATE) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY REQUIRED_DATE NULLS FIRST)
```

The main issues there are **FIRST** and **LAST** keywords - they're aggregate or analytic functions. 
**KEEP** indicates that either FIRST or LAST will be used in expression. 
**DENSE_RANK** indicates that database will use only those values, which have the minimal (FIRST) or maximal (LAST) dense rank. Dense rank calculation is based on sorting, which is set by **ORDER BY** clause.

Notice, that in your case it doesn't matter if you use MIN or MAX in main expression. This is because function "KEEP...DENSE_RANK...FIRST/LAST" described above passes to aggregate function (MIN/MAX) only those records, which already have extreme values.

Comment: Added more details and fixed possible error with NULL values by adding "NULLS FIRST".

Answer (score 0):

So you want the **MIN** and **MAX** date from the aggregated values of the LISTAGG output.

Since **LISTAGG** will always have an **ordered values**, the min date will be the **first element** in the comma delimited list, and the max date will be the **last element** in **each group**.

So, all you need to use is:

- **SUBSTR**
- **INSTR**

For example,

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT deptno, listagg(hiredate, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY deptno) dt
  3    FROM emp
  4   WHERE deptno <> 30
  5  GROUP BY deptno
  6  )
  7  SELECT deptno,
  8         dt,
  9         SUBSTR(dt, 1, instr(dt, ',', 1, 1)-1) min_dt,
 10         SUBSTR(dt, instr(dt, ',', -1, 1)+1)   max_dt
 11  FROM data
 12  /

    DEPTNO DT                                                      MIN_DT          MAX_DT
---------- ------------------------------------------------------- --------------- ----------
        10 1981-06-09,1981-11-17,1982-01-23                        1981-06-09      1982-01-23
        20 1980-12-17,1981-04-02,1981-12-03,1982-12-09,1983-01-12  1980-12-17      1983-01-12

SQL>
```

Comment: I need Min_Dt and Max_Dt for one column

Comment: @user3359056 Then just one more step, just apply `MIN` and `MAX` on the new min_dt and max_dt columns.

Comment: I didn't get what you said "Then just one more step, just apply MIN and MAX on the new min_dt and max_dt columns."

Comment: @user3359056 Can you post an example. Please edit your questions and add input data and your desired output.

Comment: SELECT 
          LISTAGG( 'Min Date("' || min(D.REQUIRED_DATE)  || '") '
                  || ',Max Date("' || max(D.REQUIRED_DATE)|| '") '
                , ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY D.REQUIRED_DATE)

  FROM   PO_REQUEST_ITEMS D
WHERE D.PO_REQUEST_ID=16 ORA-00978: nested group function without GROUP BY This issue having with following query